# SAS: Insert data when counter is 0 for the upcoming rows

Tags: sql, sas

I need to find the min_week when the counter is 0 and that row's week value should continue until again the counter becomes 0.

Following is an example of the Output I am looking for:

[image]

In my current output with the following code, I am getting the output as:

```
proc sql;
    create table week_min_1 as 
    select t1.*, t2.week as min_week from emp_table t1
    left join (select * from emp_table where counter = 0 group by emp having sequence = min(sequence)) t2
    on t1.emp= t2.emp
     ;
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: is min_week the same for all emp or does it change ever?

Comment: Would there be a case where week would increase?

Comment: min_week: No, it shouldn't be same and It has to change every time whenever the counter goes from 0 to 1 and so on by taking the Week's data as min_week.
week: No these are all the entries we will be expecting from an emp.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first create your sample data:

```
data have;
    input Emp $ Sequence Week Counter;
    datalines;
a001 1 2 0
a001 2 4 1
a001 3 8 2
a001 4 12 3
a001 5 24 0
a001 6 36 1
a001 7 48 2
a001 8 52 3
;
run;
```

Now we should sort our data. In this sample it is already sorted, but it's better safe than sorry.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by Emp Sequence;
run;
```

With a simple if statement we identify those min_week values.

```
data have2;
    set have;
    if counter = 0 then do;
        min_week = Week;
    end;
run;
```

And with update statement we put those values trough every row.

```
data want;
    update have2 (obs=0) have2;
    by Emp;
    output;
run;
```